# Generating all the Combinations of a vector of strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

I'm Trying to solve some UVA's problems and I want to generate all possible combination of a string's array. For example :

```
    string str[]={"abcd","efg","hij"};
```

So the program must print :

```
    >abcd efg hij
    >abcd hij efg
    >hij abcd efg
    >hij efg abcd 
    >efg abcd hij
    >efg hij abcd
```

Comment: Do you also need to print permutations that involve not all items in the array, such as `efg hij`, `hij efg`, and `hij`, for instance?

Comment: You want permutations, not combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for STL's [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) algorithm.

Applied to your example, it should look something like this:

```
std::sort (str, str+3);

std::cout << "The 3! possible permutations with 3 elements:\n";
do {
  std::cout << str[0] << ' ' << str[1] << ' ' << str[2] << '\n';
} while ( std::next_permutation(str, str+3) );
```

Comment: Why is std::sort() called before the loop. Is it needed in this case ? Because any way we are finding permutations of all the strings in the array so is pre-sorting needed in this case?

Comment: I believe the algorithm determines whether it is finished based on whether the elements are sorted or not. So if you don't sort it before, you may not get all permutations, as the algorithm thinks it is done once the elements are sorted.